Degree of $[\rho]^2-[\rho]$ with $\rho^3=1$
I have the elliptic curve $E:y^2=x^3+B$ where $B\in K^\times$ and $K$ is a field of characteristic distinct than $2,3$. I have the map $\mu:=[\rho]^2-[\rho]$ and I want to compute its degree.
My attempt is the following. I know that $\mu=[\rho]^2-[\rho]=[\rho]([\rho]-[1])$. Thus we have that $\deg(\mu)=\deg([\rho])+\deg([\rho]-[1])$. I know that $\deg([\rho])=1$, because we have that $[\rho][\rho]^2=[1]$, thus the dual isogeny of $[\rho]$ is $[\rho]^2$ and the degree of $[\rho]$ is $1$ (if you know any other way to compute the degree of $[rho]$ then plase let me know). However, I don't know how to compute the degree of $[\rho]-[1]$, which is what I have left to finish the calculation. Can someone help me?

Note that $(1-[\rho])^2 = 1-2[\rho]+[\rho^2] = -3[\rho] + (1 + [\rho] + [\rho^2])$. In particular, up to isomorphisms, $(1-[\rho])^2 = [-3]$.

@Mathmo123 Hmm I am sorry but I don't see why can we deduce $(1-[\rho])^2=[-3]$ up to iso from your previous statement. Could you maybe expand on this?

$([1] + [\rho] + [\rho^2])([1]-[\rho]) = 0$

@Mathmo123 hmm still don't see that :( why does that imply that they are equal up to iso?
